# Cannot Import Numpy even though I am in a different directory

Tags: python, numpy, nltk

I have been struggling with this error for hours.

```
>>> tagged_word = nltk.pos_tag(tokenize);
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 103, in pos_ta
g
    tagger = load(_POS_TAGGER)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 786, in load
    resource_val = pickle.load(opened_resource)
  File "C:\Python27\numpy\__init__.py", line 160, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
```

I searched online and followed the advice of making sure my working directory is different from the numpy's directory.  And I still received this error.  Does anyone have an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting that you have installed numpy in the same directory with nltk

Comment: oh... of course because it's nltk that is inheriting numpy, ok i will reinstall numpy in a different directory

Comment: I am using the numpy win32 superpack to install numpy but i cannot find a way to change the install directory, do you know how to?

Comment: could i just copy and installed files and place them elsewhere?

Comment: I don't think it will be a good idea! try `pip install numpy` for that